# Set/access env vars for React app hosted on Azure static website

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a react app hosted as a static website on azure blob storage, I need to set some variables based on the environment (like production, test, etc.)

I tried using the metadata section in the azure container for that and use it like this `console.log("Test env ===", process.env.test_env)` but this returns undefined, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing env variables in React all variable names need to start with `REACT_APP_*`